# Auto Complete I'm trying to get the ajax value what i clicked (cars), but it showing what i typed(c) in input tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

```
var rkey = document.getElementById("tags").value;
    alert(rkey);
$("#tags").autocomplete();
```

I'm trying to get the ajax value what i clicked , but it showing what i typed in input tag

```
<form>
        <label for="tags">SpecSearch</label>
        <input type="search" id="tags" name="tags" onchange="selectTemplate()">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something on the `select` event of the `autocomplete`, something like:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```